# Amazon AWS ItemLookup with 13 Digit ISBN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, isbn

I used to be able to do 13 digit ISBN lookups, but now I can't.

Here is the query for the 13-digit ISBN: 9780073380957.

http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=&ItemId=9780073380957&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-12-16T14%3A30%3A02Z&Version=2009-06-01&Signature=

Returns:
f6770ab1-9b3e-48d3-9492-750e8d773c1b0.0053760000000000TrueNewShipASINAmazon19780073380957ImagesItemAttributes1-SubmissionDateAllAWS.InvalidParameterValue9780073380957 is not a valid value for ItemId. Please change this value and retry your request.

However, the 10-digit ISBN for the same book works:

http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=&ItemId=0073380954&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-12-16T14%3A44%3A10Z&Version=2009-06-01&Signature=

I'm using pyaws, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I need to specify IdType as 'ISBN' and SearchIndex as 'Books'.

Here is the working query now:

http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=[my_key]&IdType=ISBN&ItemId=9780073380957&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-12-16T14%3A51%3A21Z&Version=2009-06-01&Signature=[signature]

Comment: Is it a charged service? I have to look up about 100,000+ ISBN's.

Comment: No, it's free but you have to use it for Amazon related things, though, I believe.

Comment: When I try to create an account Amazon asks me for a Credit Card, also I do not know under which service does this come. Can you please tell me?

Comment: Thought I found the solution, but didn't change anything for me, unfortunately. I have the exact same query parameters, but still get the error.